# How can I show the ├ or └ in Android Studio Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

```
return Scaffold(
├appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('')),
└body: Center(
   ├child: Column(
   └   ...
    ),
  ),
);
```

One Flutter project in android studio shows ├ or └ like this, but the other Flutter project doesn't show it.
Could you tell me how can I show it?

Comment: Look on TopLeft Options, Now follow this .  File->Preferences->settings->type "code"->  1.  Coder Action Widget: Show Headers  2. Coder Action: Enabled .. Marked both options then look at the topRight & click on "Turn on Settings Sync". Now restart ur VsCode.

Comment: @JBJason Sorry for late reply, and thank you for your response.
Unfortunately, I want to use Android Studio (Intellij) not VsCode. But I'll try to use VsCode if I can't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have flutter plugin, then you need to enable UI Guides.

- Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter> [x] Show UI Guides for build methods.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for late reply, and thank you for your response.
Unfortunately, the 'Show UI Guides for build methods' is already checked. Turn it off and turn it on again, nothing happened.
One flutter project shows ├ and └ but the other doesn't show in a same PC.

Comment: try to check if there are anything like workspace setting